# How to handle a boss who leaves the bathroom a mess?

Tags: professionalism, ethics

No question there. He is really disgusting.

**EVERYTIME** he goes to the bathroom, he pees everywhere and doesn't clean.

I find this awful, but I don't have the guts to tell him to clean up after himself.

There's no HR. Just me, my boss, his wife and daughters, a co-worker and an internee. It is a single bathroom, with a toilet. We are a very small company and everybody knows almost everything that happens.

What should I do?

Comment: Do his wife or daughters never follow him in? Statistically that ought to have happened by now, so I am very surprised that the matter has not already been resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a number of different approaches.

1. Go to HR, mention how the bathroom is always a disgusting mess, and they can either send out a memo to the office or put up a sign in the bathroom not to go full golden shower on the tiles.
2. Is it a multi-person bathroom (ie: you're both guys)? If so, does he pee all over the urinal when another person is in the room?
3. If the above doesn't help, consider another job, or keep a pack of clorox wipes in your pocket, or suck it up and call him out on it **after you've already brought it up with HR**. He might fire you, might not. I don't know enough about your work environment.

Also, you could secretly put up a sign.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's no HR. Just me, my boss, his wife and daughters, a co-worker and an internee. It is a single bathroom, with a toilet.

Comment: Sadly, I can't do anything secretly. It will always be found out. We are a **very** small company and everybody knows almost everything that happens.

Comment: He's a pig even with his family around.  Looks like your only choices are suck it up or leave.

Comment: @jmc I guess you really are right. But I sucked it up a lot.

Comment: You gotta just come out and say that it's disgusting and needs to stop. Have the conversation with your boss in private. I had a similar, less severe, situation where my boss refused to wash his hands after using the restroom and it bothered me because we share keyboards, pens, and other stuff you use your hands for. I brought the issue up with my boss and it was resolved immediately.

Comment: @beng I guess that's what I have to do then. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No problem, let us know how it goes

Comment: @beng I'm really sorry, but I will have to ditch this account. I used 10minutemail.com to create it to post this question. I've accepted this answer. For some reason, I can't upvote answers. I hope you get tons of upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

Tread very carefully. Most people are sensitive to these issues and considering how small your company is this could ruin your relationship with your boss.

The wife is possibly your best shot. If you can trust the wife to keep your secret, bring the issue up with her. Ask her to bring it up with boss man while keeping you out of it. She can just mention "there have been complaints" or something similar. One has to assume there might be a similar situation at home which has been going on for a while, so this approach may have limited efficacy.

You may not have HR, but someone must be managing the office - buying supplies, cleaning, managing the shared areas. Go to that person and state that the bathroom is too dirty to use and it needs to be cleaned more frequently. Don't mention your boss or anything else. Simply stating the facts removes the "personal" element. A situation exists that is hindering your ability to work effectively and it needs to be rectified. It doesn't matter who, why, or how.

Comment: I agree that mentioning it at as an issue rather than blaming anyone, to someone other than boss, is your best bet. Of course one possible outcome could be that mopping the bathroom more often is added to your list of duties.

Comment: Personally, if someone went to my wife to try and convince me of something, no matter the issue, I'd be infuriated. How old are we, two? Talk to people directly like an adult, or make use of an HR department: that's what they are for.

Comment: I somewhat doubt that this will solve it. If it happens at home, it happens at work. His wife uses the bathroom and doesn't say anything as well! In fact, his wife isn't trust-worthy. I would trust a lot more on a thief to secure my house than to her. And we are the ones who take care of keeping the space clean, but we hire a person to clean up the space (at least once every 2 weeks). I am the one who usually cleans up the toilet so I can use it without feeling that sickened.

Comment: @user35935 Then it sounds like you're in a situation where you are either unable or just afraid to do something. If you're not in an at-will employment state, you could maybe call him out on it and get severance when you're fired? Consult a lawyer.

Comment: @Dogbert Isn't it, like, overkill to call a lawyer just because my boss pees outside the toilet?

Comment: @user35935 No, please re-read my comment carefully. I was suggesting that if this issue is such a concern to you, and that you are unable or unwilling to talk to your boss directly about it, you might consider just going ahead and forcing yourself to talk to him about it. If he fires you, you might be eligible for severance pay, and can find a new job. The lawyer recommendation was in case you decide to take that route, you aren't let jobless without severance pay if you get fired for calling out your boss on being an animal.

Comment: @Dogbert: no HR department, distinct shortage of impartial parties... the spouse is as close to HR as available. Can't call the health department for the same reasons.